# Stop abolute divs moving when resizing the browser

Tags: css, html

I have created a relative container `div` with 100% width, it contains 5 `div` child elements in it.

I have set the child elements to absolute and set top and left pixel positioning.

However when I make my browser smaller my child elements move in and create scrollbars, I do not want this, I want the child elements to stay where they are for now, I do intend to learn media queries eventually but for now I just want them to stay where they are within the relative parent `div`.

Here is my test page: http://www.hotelmedeals.com/indexx.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given "left:" position in %, change them in pixel to keep them static... they are right now changing the left position as per % of the window when you reduce the size

Hope this helps!

Comment: Aaaaaah! ok thanks!

I used percentages as I couldnt work out how to keep them centered to different browser sizes as the container is 100% width.

How would I go about setting the left in pixils so that they look centered in different resolutions?

Regards
Jamie

Comment: Use float:left/right and use margins for adding space between boxes... because if you set left position in pixel it will stick to that particular position no matter what window size is.

Comment: Hmm im not quite sure If I understand how this works, I have applied float but still I cannot work out how to center 3 boxes as I need to enter pixils into 100% width parent.

Comment: You can refer to Twiter Bootstrap if you are looking for something like this: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/justified-nav.html

Comment: there are many more examples if you are looking for something like these: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html#examples